# questions on deep root fertilization

Tags: tree-care, diseases, fertilizer, lawn-repair

One of the dog wood trees in my yard does not grow healthy.  The tree care professionals recommend the so-called deep root fertilization, and I agree to move on with this operation.

Yesterday, after arriving home, I received a note placed in my mailbox .  The note states that they have applied  the deep root fertilization on the tree, and charged me $100.  I examined the surroundings of the trees, and could not find indication that is related to the operation, like a hole or a pile of fertilizer.  I am not clear how to ensure they have did the job of deep root fertilization or just put a note without doing anything since nobody is in the home at that time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally this is done by taking a long hollow spike that connects to a hose which sends water and fertilizer through the spike. The spike is then inserted into the soil maybe 1/2 way between the trunk and tree line.

If you're looking for evidence that the fertilizer was applied you can try looking for small holes under the tree canopy. They won't be very big, maybe 1/2" in diameter. Since the fertilizer is liquid you won't see any signs of it. If there is grass around where the fertilizer was applied you may sometimes see a portion of the grass get much darker green in a small circle around the injection holes but not always.

Material cost and labor involved with the actual fertilization is very small. If they took the time to drive over there and put the notice on the door I don't see why they would not take the time to do the job and jeopardize their reputation.